# Rewriting TreeView's Draw node method

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to rewrite the method like this:

```
private void myTreeView_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            //Custome properties
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, e.Node.Font, e.Node.Bounds, Color.Black);
        }
```

Everything is good, but there aren't signs near the nodes(plus/minus):

[image: pic]

They actually present and they work, but they are invisible. How to rewrite them in this method or what I did wrong ?

Comment: That doesn't compile.  There is no `e.Node.Font` property.  Are you saying the plus / minus signs in the image are NOT there?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be Node.TreeView.Font

Answer (score 1):

There are three modes for Drawing:

TreeView.DrawMode:

- **Normal**
  The TreeView will draw everything for you
- **OwnerDrawText**
  The TreeView will draw the +/- and lines for you (if ShowPlusMinus=true and ShowRootLines=true).  All you have to do to is draw the text part.
- **OwnerDrawAll**
  You have to draw everything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all those properties should be set to true.

```
 myTreeView.ShowPlusMinus = true;
 myTreeView.ShowRootLines = true;
```

The DrawMode property must be changed set to normal too.